# How to get a file(pdf) via json API call?

Tags: ajax, json, api, get

My search for this answer keeps getting interfered with because of the pdf keyword.

I'm trying to fetch a document via an API call. See below:

```
(function($) {  // Handles opening a notes list page
   displayDocument = function(documentPath) {
    console.log("reached displayDocument");

    var callApi = documentPath;
    console.log(callApi);

    var documentReq = $.ajax({      
        beforeSend: function() { showLoader(); },
        url: callApi,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/pdf',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Token ' + authToken
        }
    });

    documentReq.success(function(data) {
        console.log("Got resume " + data);
    });
    documentReq.error(function(data) {
        console.log("Failed to get resume " + JSON.stringify(data));
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

I get 200 OK back, the request goes to "error".

documentReq.error function starts spitting out this:

Failed to get resume {"readyState":4,"responseText":"%PDF-1.4\r\n%����\r\n1 0 obj\r\n<<\r\n/Type /Catalog\r\n/Pages 2 0 R\r\n>>\r\nendobj\r\n3 0 obj\r\n<<\r\n/CreationDate (D:20060515092800)\r\n/Author (aaronb)\r\n/Creator (Ikon Communications)\r\n/Producer (Ikon Communications)\r\n/Title (Aaron W)\r\n>>\r\nendobj\r\n2 0 obj\r\n<<\r\n/Type /Pages\r\n/Kids [4 0 R 5 0 R]\r\n/Count 2\r\n/Resources <<>>\r\n\r\n/MediaBox [.00 .00 595.00 842.00]\r\n>>\r\nendobj\r\n4 0 obj\r\n<<\r\n/Count 1\r\n/Type /Pages\r\n/Kids [6 0 R]\r\n/Parent 2 0 R\r\n/MediaBox [.00 .00 612.00 792.00]\r\n>>\r\nendobj\r\n5 0 obj\r\n<<\r\n/Count 1\r\n/Type /Pages\r\n/Kids [7 0 R]\r\n/Parent 2 0 R\r\n/MediaBox [.00 .00 612.00 792.00]\r\n>>\r\nendobj\r\n6 0 obj\r\n<<\r\n/Type /Page\r\n/Parent 4 0 R\r\n/Contents [8 0 R]\r\n/Resources <<\r\n/ProcSet [/PDF /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI /Text]\r\n/XObject <<\r\n/ed12522b-184c-403b-ba19-aba6d7723557 9 0 R\r\n>>\r\n\r\n>>\r\n\r\n>>\r\nendobj\r\n7 0 obj\r\n<<\r\n/Type /Page\r\n/Parent 5 0 R

So I figure I'm just missing something with how to handle the document itself, compared to a normal json call with Key: "value"s

any thoughts? or directions?

cheers in advance

Comment: Your datatype surely is not `json`